# Указатели и функции

Tags: c, указатели

Если сможете по неполному коду понять, то объясните, пожалуйста, что происходит в строке, которую я пометил восклицательными знаками

```
#include <stdio.h>

void quicksort(int (*comp)()){
    printf("lalal\n");
}

int first()
{
     return 1;
}

int second(){

    return 1;
}

int main()
{
    int a;
    a = getchar();
    quicksort((int (*)()(a ? first : second)); /* !!!!!! */

     return 0;
}
```

Мне кажется, что создается указатель на одну из функций. Один из вариантов будет таким (если я не прав, то объясните, пожалуйста, что произойдет)

```
quicksort( int (*first)())
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ваша функция

```
void quicksort(int (*comp))
```

Объявлена с параметром типа `int *`, т.е. ваше объявление эквивалентно

```
void quicksort(int *comp)
```

а скобки вокруг `(*comp)` в вашем варианте являются просто избыточными и не на что не влияющими.

Совершенно аналогичным образом тип `int (*)` в приведении типа при вызове этой функции

```
quicksort((int (*))(a ? first : second));
```

является обычным указательным типом `int *`, в описание которого кто-то просто добавил лишние ни на что не влияющие скобки.

Результат выражения `a ? first : second` имеет тип `int (*)()` - указатель на функцию. Таким образом вышепроцитированное приведение типа - это насильное приведение типа указателя на функцию к типу `int *`. Стандартный язык С не поддерживает преобразований между такими указателями. Указатели на данные разрешается приводить только к указателям на данные. Указатели на функции - только к указателям на функции.

---

Если вы хотели получить в качестве параметра в вашем `quicksort` именно указатель на функцию, то это действительно можно сделать так

```
void quicksort(int (*comp)())
```

После этого вам уже не нужно будет делать приведение типа при вызове

```
quicksort(a ? first : second);
```

Однако я бы не советовал вам без необходимости использовать такое свойство языка, как пустой список параметров `()` в объявлении функций. Если у ваших функций не должно быть параметров, то явно указывайте именно `(void)`в качестве списка параметров

```
void quicksort(int (*comp)(void))
{
  ...
  int a = comp();
  ...
}

int first(void)
{
  ...
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Вообще-то у вас получается приведение указателя на функцию (одну из двух, в зависимости от значения `a`) к указателю на `int`, каковой и передается функции `quicksort`.

Но если вы хотите *вызывать* функцию по указателю, то объявление `quicksort` должно быть иным:

```
void quicksort(int (*comp)())
```

Вот, можете взглянуть [тут](https://ideone.com/99AaFY). Если вызов вас не интересует - извините, значит, я забежал вперед...

Comment: Да, простите, именно функцию по указателю. Исправил свой код